# Disconnect TCPClient properly

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener, networkstream

I am using simple TCPClinet and TCPListener implementation for my client/server. But I have problem with detecting of clien succesfully readed all data. My problem is, that I am sometimes geting error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". I assume, that problem is on server side here:

```
await pClient.GetStream().WriteAsync(pBuffer, pOffset, pCount);
pClient.Close();
```

As you see in code above - Iam closing tcpclient right after all datas was writed, but I dont know if client already readed all data properly. Is there any nice way how to detect that all datas was recieved, or softly disconnect client (and allow writed data to be still readed), or something else? Right now I made rude hotfix by addin delay before pClient.Close() but it is not correct solution.

Comment: Use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to check the status of the connection on both client and server to see if connection closes.  Never close a connection from the server.  There is a know race condition that can occur if both client and server attempt to close a connection at same time.The results can be a connection that is half open and half closed.TCP when a connection is closed an ACK is required.  So when both client and server attempt to close at same time only one side of the connection can get the ack (because other side is already closed).  The result is you cannot make another connection.

Comment: i would suggest you to use Write( ) method instead of WriteAsync( ), in this way next line 'pClient.Close( ) will be executed after transferring whole data and to keep the process Asynchronous you may use Thread by putting this peace of code in some method and calling it from a Thread.

Comment: By default, you should be able to close a socket after the write completes just fine. The OS will "linger" the socket to ensure it has a chance to complete the write. If there's something preventing that, then it's not shown by the code above. E.g., if this is running in a Docker container which is torn down after the app exits.